# SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Tags: javascript, return

So I don't have a whole lot of experience with Javascript but I've done pretty well in the past. I have this website where I'm trying to run 'geoip' to pull two iso's to take to a certain page, this I've gotten to function perfectly. However, if said ISO completes a purchase a Thank You page is presented to them, but goes away because the 'geoip' is still in place. I've tried running a 'return' but can't seem to get the hang of it. In Sublime Text 3 it looks fine, any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://freegeoip.net/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(location) {
        // If the visitor is browsing from Australia or New Zealand.
        if (location.country_code == 'AU' || location.country_code == 'NZ') {
            // Redirect visitor to the purchasing store.
            window.location.href = 'http://example.com/order-international/';
            else {
                location.country_code == 'AU' || location.country_code == 'NZ' === window.location.href = 'http://example.com/thanks-international/') {
                return; //stop the execution of function
            } else {
                //keep on going
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As suggested by the placeholder in the title textbox, the title of your question should be a short version of your question, not a "please help me" or similar.

Comment: I've cleaned up your code formatting. Looking at the result, I suspect you have a misplaced pair of `{}` (at least, there seem to be other issues as well).

Comment: Sorry guys. I've used Stack Overflow to find content but never signed up or asked a question myself. Sorry for the code format as well. Copy/paste from Sublime Text seemed to add a weird amount of spacing.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder I appreciate that! So ultimately if I used this it should perform how I'm wanting it?

Comment: @drayellis42 You can/should edit your question.  Also, I suggest reading the help page:  http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Brad will do! Thanks guys. Still new to using this as a user as opposed to an observer. I'm on crunch time and should have paid more attention to the formatting of this site.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

First, when I cleaned up your code formatting, it became fairly clear that there are some misplaced `{}` (at least). I've tried to guess from the comments what you were really trying to do below.

Second, you've said you want to stop execution of "the function," so I'm guessing this ajax call is in some function somewhere.

What you do is make the rest of the function a function, and then *call* that from the ajax success handler if you want it to run, or don't if you don't. E.g.:

```
function yourOuterFunction() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://freegeoip.net/json/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(location) {
            // If the visitor is browsing from Australia or New Zealand.
            if (location.country_code == 'AU' || location.country_code == 'NZ') {
                // Redirect visitor to the purchasing store.
                window.location.href = 'http://example.com/order-international/';
            } else {
                // keep going
                keepGoing();
            }
        }
    });

    function keepGoing() {
        // The part you want to do after you have the ajax result
    }
}
```

I didn't quite know what you were trying to do with your `thanks-international` link, but hopefully that gets you headed the right way.